# Possible lawn fungus, brown patches have spread

Tags: lawn, fungus

I am located in the chicago suburbs with kentucky bluegrass (sorry for the typo) as the grass type. We had a mild winter and am wondering if the attached (brown patches) are fungus. I noticied it spread compared to last year. Thank you.

[image]

Bentgrass image

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the white stuff on the left residual snow? Just wondering cos you said your winter was unusually mild... otherwise, for diagnostic purposes, clear close up photos of the brown patches is necessary.

Comment: Added a close up, we had inches this year and temps above 30 mostly. Usually we get several feet with negative temps. Thank you.

Comment: Do you live anywhere near a golf course? Could you have bentgrass encroaching?

Comment: I do have bengrass in my yard and will post a picture and am going to use glyphosate on it. Is 3 apps good? Thanks.